# Real-Time Audio Streaming with HTML5

Tags: html, audio, streaming

I want to make a real time audio streaming software. The server is a windows application while the client should be written in HTML5.

Would this be possible?
If yes, what codec/protocol could be used?

EDIT: My question is about HTML5, not windows. In a custom software application it is possible to do anything. But I don't know about HTML5 audio capabilities.

Comment: This isn't a SO question really - it is more for help with code you have attempted to write. I doubt you will get an answer here (hopefully I am wrong) - you will get answers to questions if you show some code you have attempted to write in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In general you're asking where i can play live content with html5 browser.
Simple answer : you should use HLS for Android(4+) & iOS devices(iphone/ipad). as for desktop you can use mpeg-dash for chrome/firefox/IE11 and any other browser that support media element.